# Do isomorphisms preserve simplicity?

Tags: group-theory

This is a very simple* question that I surprisingly can't find the answer to, and I am too stupid to come up with a counterexample or a proof. So does simplicity of one group and an isomorphism between two groups imply the other group is simple? Thank you very much!

*Pun unintended

Comment: Yes. Anything you can say with group words is preserved. If $N\unlhd G$ then $f(N)\unlhd H$ for any isomorphism $f:G\to H$. Moreover, since $f$ is a bijection proper containment/non-triviality is also preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon G\to G'$ be a surjective homomorphism. If $N'$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$, then
$$
N=\{x\in G:f(x)\in N'\}
$$
is easily seen to be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Suppose $N'\subsetneq G'$: what can you say about $N$?

Now, assume $f$ is also injective and that $\{1\}\subsetneq N'$; what can you say about $N$?

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphisms between two groups $G$ and $H$ indeed preserve simplicity. Let $N \vartriangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be an isomorphism. Then $f(N) \vartriangleleft H$ (it follows directly from the definition of a normal subgroup). But if $L \vartriangleleft H$, then $f^{-1}(L)\vartriangleleft G$, since $f^{-1}$ is also an isomorphism. Hence $G,H$ have the same amount of normal subgroups.

Comment: Ah, it seems to obvious now. Thank you very much.